# Multiple history autocomplete in VSCode Powershell terminal

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I have no idea what I did, but my shell started to show autocomplete from history
Just *one* of them, the other terminal tabs don't have this

The question it, how did I do that? I'd like to use it every time.

[image]

(This is certainly not `Ctrl+R` `bck-i-search` - that's just one line)

Comment: In short: In-session, press F2 to toggle between in-line and list-view predictions. To persistently switch to list-view predictions, put `Set-PSReadLineOption -PredictionViewStyle ListView` in your `$PROFILE` file. See the linked duplicate for details.